# Enable PostGIS extension on Ubuntu 14.04.2

Tags: postgresql

I have troubles enabling PostGIS extension on Ubuntu 14.04.2 and PostgreSQL 9.3. I have installed the packages with this step by step [procedure](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostGIS21UbuntuPGSQL93Apt).

PostgreSQL and pgAdminIII seem to be installed properly. I can launch pgAdminIII and the localhost default server exists. I add a new DB and type in `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;`. I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/9.3/extension/postgis.control": Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
```

Could anyone help? I think I'm not far from success...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are getting a "file not found" error, so please verify that you have installed version 9.3 of the extension and not 9.4 that is described in the link you provide. You may also install it through the Ubuntu software center. Just type "postgis" in the search field.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must install `postgis` and `postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1` packages and create postgis extension on your database

```
sudo apt-get install postgis postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1
sudo -u postgres psql -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis; CREATE EXTENSION postgis_topology;" DATABASE_NAME_HERE
```

Reference: [Jon Saints' Tutorial](http://www.saintsjd.com/2014/08/13/howto-install-postgis-on-ubuntu-trusty.html)

Answer (score -1):

```
wget http://download.osgeo.org/postgis/source/postgis-2.1.8.tar.gz
tar xfvz postgis-2.1.8.tar.gz
cd postgis-2.1.8
./configure --with-pgconfig=/usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/bin/pg_config --without-raster
make && make install
```

Now there was a problem for me in that the `postgis` library can't see the `proj` library, as can be seen from the 'not found' when executing `ldd /usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/lib/postgis-2.1.so`. The solution was to softlink it:

```
ln /usr/local/lib/libproj.so.9.1.0 /usr/lib/libproj.so.9
```